# putting validation on datepicker component of vuejs but its showing up the the error message by default

Tags: validation, vue.js, datepicker

//this is my html code where i have a datepicker component wheer i want to throw a validation but i want the error message to be shown once the user leaves this feild and go on some other inputfeild of the form

```
<datepicker  v-model="present_complaint.experienceSince"
 name="date" placeholder=24-july-1994>
</datepicker>
<span class="error-msg"  v-show="present_complaint.experienceSince ==''">
Date is a mandatory field
</span>
```

//this is my js code

```
present_complaint:{
  description:'',
}
```

//currently when the page loads by default the error message is there on the datepicker as by default it is empty now i want that it should only be diaplayed when user clicks on it and leave it not selecting any date basically when it goes to any other feild and not selecting any date

Comment: Please provide more code and more information to your question in order your question to be more specific.Many people can give you right solutions but not the solution you currently want.

Answer (score -2):

> I have a solution for you.

```
<div id="app">

  <input type="text" placeholder="type something" v-model.trim="text" @blur="blur">
  <span v-show="text === ''">Please Fill the input</span>

</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    text: null
  },
  methods: {
    blur() {
      if(this.text === null) {
        this.text = ''
      }
    }
  }
})
```

*The answer it is simplified to understand the logic.Once you do,you can solve your problem by replacing some code.Take a look to the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/eywraw8t/50940/)*

Comment: sorry this is not working in my case here i dnt have an input field its a component of vuejs named  datepicker

Comment: yes i said it is a simplified answer.Once you catch the logic you will be able to write the solution in your problem.